# ViewHolder ItemView clickListener not working after adding some xml attributes to cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-cardview, android-viewholder

ViewHolder itemView.OnClickListener(this) is working perfectly for the first time, which calls this method **onListClick.onSectionListItemClick** when the itemView is clicked. But Now when I added some of these attributes to ItemViewHolder layout in cardview section, the itemView.OnClickListener(this) is not working, **onListClick.onSectionListItemClick()** method is not called . So is there anything, I am missing? Please check this out.

**item_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/grey" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/item_done_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check"
                android:tint="@color/primary" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ItemViewHolder.java**

```
class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView sectionItemTitle;
    private ImageButton sectionItemDoneIndicator;

    ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        sectionItemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        sectionItemDoneIndicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_done_indicator);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        onListClick.onSectionListItemClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

Comment: is your CardView the parent of your list layout?

Comment: @elmorabea I just updated the xml file. Please checkout the item_layout.xml

Comment: why don't you just make cardview parent, i guess the touch intercept is consumed by some one else.

Comment: The problem is resolver after making the reference to cardView and set the click listener to the cardView. Now, I just want to know why this things happens ?